# How to code an update for extended field using server action on Odoo 11?

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-11

I am learning Odoo 11 and want to code a button which will call a python method through a Server action.

Here's my button code:

```
<button name="enviarfactura" type="action" string="Homologar" attrs="{'invisible':['|',('sent','=',True), ('state', 'not in', ('open','paid'))]}"/>
```

Here's my action.server code

```
<record model="ir.actions.server" id="x_nc_act_serv_fact">
  <field name="name">enviarfactura</field>
  <field name="model_id" ref="model_account_invoice"/>
  <field name="sequence">1</field>
  <field name="type">ir.actions.server</field>
  <field name="state">code</field>
  <field name="code">
            if records: 
               action = records.x_nc_met_fac()
  </field>
</record>
```

And finally here's my python method.

```
@api.multi
def x_nc_met_fac(self):
for rec in self:
    self.x_nc_fld_fact = True
    self.x_nc_fld_det_fact = 'my custom text'
```

Now the logic for this is that, the button will call the server.action which will call the method on my python class. The method will set new values for extended fields on the model account.invoice
In theory this should work, but it doesn't.

Discarding possible mistakes:

-It's might not be the python indentation. The python community on discord help me with it :P
-It's not the server.action structure since when I upload my module containing this code it creates the server.action without any problem.
-When I click on the button, nothing happens.So i tried changing the type of the button to `"type=object"` and tell it the name of my method it gives the error. Account.invoice has no attribute "x_nc_met_fac"

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure in which class is your x_nc_met_fac method but if its inherited in an account.invoice class and you have an object button it should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `name` of the button has to be the action ID. So two thinks have to be done:

1. Your action should be defined before the button. If both are in the same xml, it's easy, if not check the order in your module manifest. XMLs will be loaded in that order!
2. Change button `name` to an "external ID substitution"

```xml
<button name="%(x_nc_act_serv_fact)d" type="action" string="Homologar"
    attrs="{'invisible':['|',('sent','=',True), ('state', 'not in', ('open','paid'))]}"/>
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! YOU ARE A GOD! But actually your answer was partially correct. After correcting the button xml, i had to correct my method too. Since the "for loop" i defined, should be inside the method :P Then i had to order everything i had on my view.xml Odoo doesn't tell you this on the documentation. So I took a look at their addons and saw each type of object is on a different  .xml Every type of view, type of actions, type of menu are on separated .xml files and then called on the manifest. I had no idea about this, but this solved my problem and now it works like a charm!

Comment: I was only looking for the button ;-) and there is something in the documentation, eg [here](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/guidelines.html). Nice to know everything is solved now :-)